# Facebook send notification to friends using the app when a user joins my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I want to notify user's friends, those that are already using my app that a friend of his has also installed the app.

I see a few apps having a number on the app's and games block. Is there a way of doing it. How do these apps do it. Also can i send a Notification (i.e on the globe icon)

I already have the list of users to notify. How do i notify them in the facebook.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the receiver to take action when they receive the notification, you can use the [Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) functionality and the [Request Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). The Request Dialog sends a request from one user to one or more users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you meant in the 2nd paragraph, but if I somehow managed to understand something it is that you are asking how you can notify the users.
There are a few methods with which you can notify the user, and they are all covered in the [Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) doc.

If you want to only notify a user's friends that already have the app installed you'll have to first find out which users qualify, you have two options for that:

(1) Using the [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) you can make a request to: *[/me/friends?fields=installed](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends%3Ffields%3Dinstalled)* which should return a list of users, the ones that have the app installed will have this form:

```
{
    "installed": true, 
    "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

The ones who don't have the app will be of this form:

```
{
    "id": "USER_ID"
}
```

(2) You can use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) to check who are the friends who have the app installed using [this query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20not%20is_app_user%20and%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29):

```
SELECT 
    uid
FROM 
    user 
WHERE 
    is_app_user 
    AND 
    uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Comment: Sorry buddy but i already have the list of users. How do i notify them  in the facebook.

Comment: There's a link in my answer to the "Social Channels" document, in there all of the available options are explained.